# Unable to maximize window manually or have fullscreen mode in selenium-side-runner

Tags: selenium-webdriver, fullscreen, selenium-ide, chrome-options, selenium-side-runner

I've been trying through either sending the key combination {Fn} +{F11} or {F11} alone in order to maximize window through the steps which seem to not affect side-runner's window behavior at all. Changing window size is not working as well.

Cmd query looks like:

```bash
selenium-side-runner -c "browserName=chrome chromeOptions.args=[--start-fullscreen]" --filter test_advanced C:\Users\dan\side\test.side
```

Is there any way to maximize window through selenium-side-runner? Tested in Windows 10 and 11.